# What is unexprected T_ELSE in php?

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax-error

I'm just learning php...but I can't seem to find the source of this error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in your code on line 4

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])){
                if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["language"]) || empty($_POST["comment"]));
                    {$error=true;}
                else
                {$to="fu@gmail.com";
                $subject="You have a new comment from fu.com";
                $body=$_POST["name"]." says"."\n".$POST["comment"]."primary language is"."\n".$POST["language"]."and email is"."\n".$POST["email"];
                $headers="From: fu.com\r\n";
                mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);}}
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of this line: `if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["language"]) || empty($_POST["comment"]));`

Comment: formatting is important. When asking a question, first format your code so that humans like us can read it. The edit someone made to your code immedately showed the problem by virtue of that `if` ending in a semi-colon, instead of being followed by `{` to start the conditional code block.

Comment: answers from all the heavy hitters, impressive

Comment: You have just two syntax errors: This should work.   
 if (isset($_POST["action"])){     
     if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["language"])|| empty($_POST["comment"])){
         $error=true;
         
     }else
        {
         $to="fu@gmail.com";
         $subject="You have a new comment from fu.com";
         $body=$_POST["name"]." says"."\n".$POST["comment"]."primary language is"."\n".$POST["language"]."and email is"."\n".$POST["email"];
         $headers="From: fu.com\r\n";
         mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);}  
                
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a semi-colon at the end of your IF statement instead of a curly brace:

```
if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) || 
    empty($_POST["language"]) || empty($_POST["comment"])); // <-- HERE
                {$error=true;}
            else
```

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
if ([...snip...]));   <--this ";" TERMINATES the if()
  { ... }
  else
  { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Spurious semi-colon at the end of

```
if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["language"]) || empty($_POST["comment"]));
```